# The problem that I have is that I can't move the font awesome icon from right even if I use position also.I tried using margins also,it didn't work

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

How do I position my font awesome icon from right.

-this is my html code with font awesome icons

```
<div class="part-3">
    <div class="box">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-galactic-senate"></i>
        <h1>Ui Design</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum</p>
        <a href="#" class="right-arrow" >KNOW MORE<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="box red-box">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-codepen"></i>
        <h1>Product Design</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum</p>
        <a href="#" class="right-arrow">KNOW MORE<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-mandalorian"></i>
        <h1>Branding</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum</p>
        <a href="#" class="right-arrow">KNOW MORE<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please post the CSS you used and explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.